# Passing file path like C:\data\abc.zip in the JSON or CSV file as input file for the POST Request using Postman with newman

Tags: json, csv, postman, newman

My requirement is 
either .csv or JSON file should have
the one of the columns as Filepath where I need to give the Zip file path using POSTMAN tool

How will it take the file path from the input file (.csv) and execute dynamically? Do we need to use any environment variable, pls let me know.

Comment: Do you want to upload the file??

Comment: @SeleniumUser - Can you please a bit more specific?